# Get DOM loaded javascript from browser

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, rhino

I want to get the javascript code that is loaded in DOM.

For example i want to get the script loaded by DOM by following call

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
```

and get exactly the copy which browser has loaded.

Problem came because i want to run some external js in Rhino Engine from java and i can't pass it via scope as it won't recognize so if i have DOM resolved js file than i can directly put it for run.

Comment: Just copy that URL into your browser's address bar.

Comment: Pointy i don't think you got the question i need to get functions which is loaded in DOM. If you go by URL than it will give script having global declaration and all so i need it to be resolved and get it